# Dynamic instrumentation with Clang

Tags: c, clang

I'm trying to get up to speed on using Clang by doing a bit of dynamic code instrumentation with C (and maybe C++) where I take a source file and generate an instrumented output.  I'd like to add a function call at the beginning of any block and also change all boolean expressions to call some function so I can track that too. For example:

```
foo = a && (b || c);
```

would become something like:

```
foo = EXPR_AND(a, EXPR_OR(b, c));
```

and thus I can track all combinations of conditions that occur.

I assume using a RecursiveASTVisitor would be the best approach, but is there an easy way to output the C code for each node I visit?

Any suggestions of what to look at to accomplish something like this would be most appreciated!

Note: After some further investigation, I just discovered libclang which looks like it could be my best friend.  Coupled with a rewriter, I might just have what I need.  Any pointers to good examples (I just found the excellent Apple developers meeting video on libclang) would be great.

Comment: Your proposed transform greatly changes the semantics of the code if `b` or `c` contain any side effects...

Comment: Actually, EXPR_AND and EXPR_OR are macro expansions that look something like:
#define EXPR_AND(a, b) (a ? instr[0] = 1 : instr[1] = 1,0) && (b ? instr[2] = 0 : instr[3] = 1,0)

Answer (score 2):

For a good example see [this project](https://github.com/yotamr/traces).

It uses clang in order to instrument call function entering and exit, and it also inspects types of passed arguments.