# Instrumenting C/C++ code using clang

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, instrumentation, llvm-clang

I would like to add some instructions to C/C++ programs from within clang without using an LLVM pass. I know it is possible but I can't find any documentation on how to do so.

As an example, given the program below

```
// before instrumentation
int main() {
    int num = 0;
    printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

I would like to be able to add arbitrary instructions from within clang and create a program like

```
// after instrumentation
int main() {
    int num = 0;
    if(num != 0) {    // inserted code
        // do stuff   // inserted code
    }                 // inserted code
    printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

I found some projects that instrument code using clang ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888080/how-to-instrument-a-statement-just-before-another-statement-using-clang), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946060/dynamic-instrumentation-with-clang)) but not any concrete documentation.

Comment: You mention "C/C++".  Does this mean you are mixing C and C++?  Otherwise, you should talk about C or C++.  (Besides, the C language does not have `cout` and doesn't have the overload for `operator<<`.

Comment: Making changes to a compiler is evil.  When you change compilers, you'll have to port the same changes and many compilers can't be modified as easily.

Comment: The instructions to be added might change between C/C++ but I assume the process of adding them remains the same. Also for the purposes of this question assume I want to be evil and instrument the code from clang.

Comment: I believe GCC/G++ can do it, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850548/how-can-i-plant-assembly-instructions-in-the-prologue-and-epilogue-of-function-v

Comment: I need to use clang